# Google API Directions error while reading JSONObejct

Tags: android, json, google-maps-android-api-2

In my app i use a Google Place Picker for get coordinates of location that user would travel to and with Google API Directions i get the distance in KM but sometime i get this error in the log and don't get the distance and time:

```
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:293)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:521)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at com.ddz.assistenteauto.Fragments.TravelFragment$4.onResponse(TravelFragment.java:249)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at com.ddz.assistenteauto.Fragments.TravelFragment$4.onResponse(TravelFragment.java:236)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
10-21 20:30:23.326 4920-4920/com.ddz.assistenteauto W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here how i send request to Google with http request:

```
private void getDistanceTime(TravelInfo obj){

    Log.d(TAG, "getDistanceTime()");
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + obj.getStartLat() + "," + obj.getStartLng() + "&destination=" + obj.getEndLat() + "," + obj.getEndLng() + "&mode=driving&sensor=false";

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    //mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                    //Log.i(TAG,"Response is: "+ response);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        // routesArray contains ALL routes
                        JSONArray routesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                        // Grab the first route
                        JSONObject route = routesArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        // Take all legs from the route
                        JSONArray legs = route.getJSONArray("legs");
                        // Grab first leg
                        JSONObject leg = legs.getJSONObject(0);
                        //take travel distance
                        JSONObject distanceObject = leg.getJSONObject("distance");
                        String distance = distanceObject.getString("text");
                        //Take travel duration
                        JSONObject durationObject = leg.getJSONObject("duration");
                        String duration = durationObject.getString("text");

                        //Set distance and duration to the class infoTravel that contain coordinates
                        setDistanceTime(distance, duration);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
            Log.i(TAG,"That didn't work!");
        }
    });
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Someone can help?

And can i get user position from PlacePicker?
From now i use this for getting user position:

```
private void getUserLocation() {

    Log.i(TAG, "getUserLocation()");
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        // Logic to handle location object
                        String stringStartLat, stringStartLng;

                        travelInfo.setStartLat(location.getLatitude());
                        travelInfo.setStartLng(location.getLongitude());
                        stringStartLat = Double.toString(travelInfo.getStartLat());
                        stringStartLng = Double.toString(travelInfo.getStartLng());
                        //Set the TextView in the fragment with start coordinates
                        startLatView.setText(stringStartLat);
                        startLngView.setText(stringStartLng);

                        if (travelInfo.getEndLat() != 0 && travelInfo.getEndLng() != 0) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Dentro if userlocation");
                            getDistanceTime(travelInfo);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

EDIT

When i get the JSON error i receive this JSON from Google API

```
10-21 20:54:18.965 22814-22814/com.ddz.assistenteauto I/TravelFragment: Response is: {
                                                                           "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_",
                                                                           "routes" : [],
                                                                           "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
                                                                        }
```

EDIT

I add the key to the URL but still get error:

```
String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + obj.getStartLat() + "," + obj.getStartLng() + "&destination=" + obj.getEndLat() + "," + obj.getEndLng() + "&mode=driving&AIza*****************FI";
```

EDIT 2 now with the key i get this error:

```
10-22 15:24:35.540 27362-27362/com.ddz.assistenteauto I/TravelFragment: Response is: {
                                                                           "error_message" : "Requests to this API must be over SSL. Load the API with \"https://\" instead of \"http://\".",
                                                                           "routes" : [],
                                                                           "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
```

So i change the http to https... and let's see
                                                                        }

Comment: In the last update looks like you a missing `&key=`, it should be `&mode=driving&key=AIza*****************FI` instead of `&mode=driving&AIza*****************FI`

Comment: You are right! Thanks....see if now works :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear and says that you are exceeding a quota and your Directions API request doesn't use an API key.

Please note that keyless access to Google web services uses a shared quota, even if you don't send too many requests other users without API keys can send many requests and consume a common quota.

In order to fix the issue you have to create a project in Google Cloud developer console, activate Directions API web service and generate an API key. Then you can apply the key in your requests:

`String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + obj.getStartLat() + "," + obj.getStartLng() + "&destination=" + obj.getEndLat() + "," + obj.getEndLng() + "&mode=driving&key=YOUR_API_KEY";`

You can safely remove `sensor` it's outdated and not required anymore.

For further details please refer to the Directions API documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key

**UPDATE**

You should also correctly handle the possible values of [status](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponseElements#StatusCodes) in the response. Sometimes you can get ZERO_RESULTS, NOT_FOUND or UNKNOWN_ERROR, in this case the `routes` element doesn't exist or is empty in the response and this leads to the exception that you observe in your code.

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

    //Get status first
    String status = jsonObject.getString("status");

    if (status.equals("OK")) {
        // routesArray contains ALL routes
        JSONArray routesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
        // Grab the first route
        JSONObject route = routesArray.getJSONObject(0);
        // Take all legs from the route
        JSONArray legs = route.getJSONArray("legs");
        // Grab first leg
        JSONObject leg = legs.getJSONObject(0);
        //take travel distance
        JSONObject distanceObject = leg.getJSONObject("distance");
        String distance = distanceObject.getString("text");
        //Take travel duration
        JSONObject durationObject = leg.getJSONObject("duration");
        String duration = durationObject.getString("text");
        //Set distance and duration to the class infoTravel that contain coordinates
        setDistanceTime(distance, duration);
    } else if (status.equals("NOT_FOUND")) {
        //TODO: handle not found
    } else if (status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")) {
        //TODO: handle zero results
    } else if (status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT")) {
        //TODO: handle over query limit
    }
    .....

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

            }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, yes i have a google api keys included in the Manifest and i think that i take automatically.... i put the api key into url... i will try if the problem is solved..
Yes i have activated direction to Google Cloud and Places :)

Did you know witch street is occurred in the "distance" that the JSON contain?
Is the best/short street for the travel?

Comment: The API key that you use in manifest has Android app restriction, it won't work with web services. You have to generate new API key in order to use it with web service. Note that web service API keys support only IP restrictions, but in case of mobile app you cannot know IP addresses of devices where the app is installed, so try to use unrestricted key.

Comment: Directions API usually returns the fastest route, there is no way to get a shortest route.

Comment: Fine, i use it for calculate the percurred distance with car :)
But i don't select Android restriction in the configuration i need to generate another key anyway?

Comment: Do you mean Google Maps Android API shows map for unrestricted key? Usually it gives authentication error, you need Android app restriction if you want to see a map: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#detailed-guides

Comment: When i create a Key for my project i not select a "restriction"...android key, http key etc etc...
But i still receive error from JSON sometime.... so as you say i try to create a new Key with http restriction.

No i haven't a map in the App...i only need PlacePicker for get user travel destination and Direction api for get total distance travel..

Comment: HTTP referer restriction won't work with web service request neither it's for client side APIs like Maps JavaScript API. Did you add a key parameter in your request string? Anyway in your code before you run `JSONArray routesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");` you should check a status value of response and proceed only if status is OK, otherwise handle other status. It might be ZERO_RESULTS or UNKNOWN_ERROR. Your code doesn't handle all possible status codes. Have a look at   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponseElements#StatusCodes

Comment: yes i add my key to the http request.
And i set Enable to the Google Cloud to: Google Maps API Android, Google Maps Direction API, Google Place API Android (for Place Picker) but i still get the same error... i edit my for and add the new url that i send.

Comment: You just need to handle status codes from responses to avoid the exception.